# React Context State setter not firing useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have set up a side-effect with a dependency which is coming from a context. The context contains a state object and its setter, and the side-effect should be triggered every time the state object is changed. However this is not happening.

This is a minimal example. I'm first creating a context ready to take a state and its setter as follows

```js
const DestinationsContext = createContext({
  destinations: [],
  setDestinations: () => {}
});
```

In app.js I then use the context with a provider, passing in a state object and its setter as follows

```js
function App() {
  const [destinations, setDestinations] = useState([]);
  return (
    <DestinationsContext.Provider value={{ destinations, setDestinations }}>
      <Menu />
    </DestinationsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Inside the Menu component, I then have a `useEffect` running as follows

```js
function Menu() {
  const { destinations } = useContext(DestinationsContext);
  { menuItems, setMenuItems } = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuItems(destinations.map(destination => <DestinationItem />))
  }, [destinations]);

  return <ul>{ menuItems }</ul>
```

In another component, I have a form, where the submit handler is doing as follows

```js
const { destinations, setDestinations } = useContext(DestinationsContext);
const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setDestinations(previousDestinations => {
    previousDestinations.splice(index, 0, new Destination(...));
    return previousDestinations;
  }
}
```

Although the `destinations` do get updated when the form is submitted, the effect in the `Menu` component doesn't get triggered, when I'm expecting that it should. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `submitHandler` might be mutating state before setting it, perhaps try:

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setDestinations((previousDestinations) => {
    const newDestinations = [...previousDestinations];
    newDestinations.splice(index, 0, new Destination(...));
    return newDestinations;
  });
};
```

Perhaps also check if another component is wrapped in `DestinationsContext.Provider`:

```
function App() {
  const [destinations, setDestinations] = useState([]);
  return (
    <DestinationsContext.Provider value={{ destinations, setDestinations }}>
      <Menu />
      <AnotherComponent />
    </DestinationsContext.Provider>
  );
```

Besides, depending on the usage, maybe `useEffect` could possibly be omitted since `destinations` is already being updated by `useContext`:

```
function Menu() {
  const { destinations } = useContext(DestinationsContext);
  return <ul>{destinations.map(destination => <DestinationItem />)}</ul>
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, copying `previousDestinations` to a new variable, and modifying and returning that instead did the trick.
Also many thanks for pointing out I could get rid of `useEffect` completely. I'm new to React, even if experienced as a programmer, and as I'm learning as I go, that helped me look into that particular aspect of React.

Answer (score 0):

probably because destinatons itself is an array, try to use `JSON.stringify`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMenuItems(destinations.map(destination => <DestinationItem />))
}, [JSON.stringify(destinations)])
```

Also you can check on change of length in destinations array

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMenuItems(destinations.map(destination => <DestinationItem />))
}, [destinations.length])
```